# How to get all properties named ref from a json using jmespath?

Tags: normalization, jsonpath, jmespath

I have a json which is as below:

```
{
  "ref": "a",
  "details": {
     "ref": "b",
     "properties": [
        { "ref": "c" },
        { "ref": "d" }
     ]
  }
}
```

I want to get all the values whose property is "$ref" using JMESpath.

I tried *.*.ref but it didn't work.

Output should be: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Answer (score 2):

You tagged JSON Path as well, so here's that answer.  Not sure about JMESPath.

You need to start your path with a `$`.

```
$..ref
```

You can see that it works [here](https://jsonpath.com/).

[image: action]

Comment: yeah I am aware about jsonpath and got to know the JMESPath does not have ancestry concept. So if you want to access deeply nested properties JMESPath assumes that you know the structure.